# Declaring variable and different widgets inside a loop or a condition using dart in Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I am completely new to flutter and really I don't have a good background in App development.
I am trying to write a code where I need to declare a loop and inside the loop, I need to have different conditions and a few variables. The problem is if I start writing some loop and then I can't put more widgets in the loop I am able to put only one widget inside it.
Please see the image below I want to write a code inside my Widget
[See when I start declaring a few things after the widget then it not accepting it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFoul.png)

Comment: Please, do not post your code as images

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are looping inside a Widget, and you are expected to return a single Widget.

To return a list you must do the above:

```
List<Widget> _myList(){
   List<Widget> list = [];
   for(var i = 0; i<10; i++){
      list.add(your widget);
   }
   return list;
}
```

And use this function on return of children, like this:

```
TextSpan(children: _myList());
```

On this way you will create a function that return a List and call it when the children that u are expecting a List.

Comment: Yeah, Thank you. It's working.